# How to extract the JSON data from the nested arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, api, import

So I am pulling the API from Coinmarketcap.com and the new version has a really different data structure.

Also I am a newb at PHP and APIs really don't understand how to pull the nested array data out of the api call.

Here is the api data:
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/
or 
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?structure=array

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Bitcoin", 
            "symbol": "BTC", 
            "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
            "rank": 1, 
            "circulating_supply": 17148000.0, 
            "total_supply": 17148000.0, 
            "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 6233.51, 
                    "volume_24h": 3674820000.0, 
                    "market_cap": 106892229480.0, 
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.11, 
                    "percent_change_24h": -0.46, 
                    "percent_change_7d": -6.25
                }
            }, 
            "last_updated": 1531544203
        }
    ], 
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1531543852, 
        "error": null
    }
}
```

What I decided to do is pull the object into `json_dcode` and then loop through it creating a new array each time until I was able to grab the array data i wanted, which in this case was `$a()`. This worked, but I thought there might be a more efficient way of doing this as i think the for-loops will cause performance issues. Is there a better way to do this? thank you in advance. -Dan

Here is my test code please show me a better way:

```
 <?php
$BitcoinContents = file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/1/?structure=array");
$BTCContents = json_decode($BitcoinContents, true);
echo " 0 <br>";
print_r($BTCContents);
echo "<br>";

foreach($BTCContents as $array){
  echo "<br>--------<br>";
  print_r($array);
  foreach($array as $arr){
    echo "<br>--------<br>";
    print_r($arr);
    foreach($arr as $ar){
      echo "<br>--------<br>";
      print_r($ar);
      foreach($ar as $a){
        echo "<br>--------<br>";
        print_r($a);
        foreach($a as $key => $val){
          echo "<br>=========<br>";
          echo "$key: $val | ";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


echo "<br>=========<br>"; 
echo "<br>--------<br>";
      print_r($a); 
echo "<br>--------<br>";
echo "<br>=========<br>"; 
echo "<br>".$a['price']."<br>";

echo "<br>--------<br>";
echo "<br>=========<br>";
```

?>

Comment: Why not use array index like `$data['take']['from']['here']`?

Comment: Um i don't know how to do that... can you explain? (total newbie to PHP) do you mean 'BTCContents['data']['quotes']['USD']['price']` instead of my `$a['price']` ?

Comment: Yep,  that's it.Just print_r at various indexes to see where you've reached.You need loop only when you want to retrieve all the entries at a specific index.

Answer (score 2):

If your are trying to access a particular array in a nested array, just do this:

```
$data = $BTCContents['data'][0]['quotes']['USD'];
```

Here I have used the index of the arrays to access a specific array which is USD.
Index of array = Name of the array which can be a word or digit.

Then you can do a foreach loop to access the item inside or you can access them directly by doing:

```
$price = $data['price'];
```

Comment: Excellent, that totally worked. I tried it out here https://crytodentaku.com/index2.php thank you so much. tried to up tick your answer but i have less than 15 reputation points.

Comment: side question, why did we have to put the `[0]` in this?

Comment: If you print_r($BTCContents), you will see there are different indexes. These indexes are use to access a particular array. There are different types of arrays which you can read here: [https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp] .
When you get inside $BTCContents['data'] array, if you do a print_r($BTCContents['data']) the new index to reach _id_, _name_, _quotes_ and the other data is 0.
Sometimes the indexes is a word or digit.